# Unauthenticated Pairing failed - Bluez

Tags: bluez, nrf52840

I am able to pair my nrf52832 after with the nrf connect phone app
But when trying to do the same with Bluez I am getting authentication error
I use the bluetoothctl tool to do the test ....
Please see the example below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIdAL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ1Dq.png)
this is the btmon debug of the session when trying the pairing

Any idea why the pairing is failing all the time although I am able to pair using the nrf connect phone app ?
Thanks a lot

I tried to change the pair command with no arguments still getting :

pair DE:D1:E9:6D:55:8C
Attempting to pair with DE:D1:E9:6D:55:8C
hci0 DE:D1:E9:6D:55:8C auth failed with status 0x05 (Authentication Failed)
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
hci0 DE:D1:E9:6D:55:8C type LE Random disconnected with reason 2